# Why do link paths in JavaScript not require a precedding / but paths in PHP includes do?

Tags: php, javascript

Sounds nit picky but this had me hung up for about an hour or so.

I have a path set like this in JavaScript

```
const JAVASCRIPT =              'host/source/ArcJB.js';
```

which renders in my document like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="host/source/ArcJ.js"></script>
```

If I put in a preceding `/` it breaks the link.

In PHP, for server-side paths I use:

```
<?php
    include_once getcwd() . "/host/source/class.ControlEntry.php";
```

If I don't put in the `/` it breaks things.

I guess conceptually how am I suppose to know this so I don't have to pull my hair out with trial and error?

Also noted:

Paths inside my .js file work with either a `/` or not a `/` preceding the path.

These are used for image lookup or ajax calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preceding slash is used to denote the path should be considered as an absolute path, which means,

1. For your Js path, which resides in a HTML file which is parsed by a browser to render its content, it should append what you wrote to the domain to get the file. And if your Js file is located relatively to the current page your snippet is located, the link may break.
2. For your php file, it is located in a path which can be accessed by following system root to `host/source/class.ControlEntry.php`

Answer (score 6):

You should be aware that the paths you pass to `include_once` are resolved on the server itself while the paths in Javascript are resolved by the browser. Both basically follow the same rules:

- paths starting with `/` are resolved absolutely. On the server, this is the root directory (i.e. the topmost directory). In the browser, this is basically concatenating the host and the path that you are specifying.
- paths not starting with a `/` are relatively resolved, i.e. against the current directory on the server and against the path in your browser.

Realize that `getcwd()` returns a directory like `/var/www`. If you then just concanate `host/source/class.ControlEntry.php` to it, it will yield `/var/wwwhost/source/class.ControlEntry.php`. On most (if not, all) PHP SAPI's, you can leave out the `getcwd()` thing when including a file as the current directory is already being searched when including files. In this case, you do not need the `/` either.

Finally, **the server file paths do not have to match the URLs**! `http://example.com/script.php` can be located at `/var/www/script.js`. If you refer to `/script.php` in a HTML file, it will be resolved correctly. On the other hand, you should not try `include "/script.php"`, that will search for a file `script.php` in the root of your filesystem which is most often not what you are looking for.

Comment: paths starting wiht / inside my .js are not resolved absolutely, whether or not I use a / does not matter.

Comment: @CS_2013 `/` is resolved against the domain. If your webapp is located at `http://example.com/app/`, then `/script.js` will be searched on `http://example.com/script.js`.

Comment: /folder/source/class.ControlEntry.php resolves to A. A is equal to the http://example.com/entry_point....

Comment: @CS_2013 It will, clear your cache and use Firebug or another traffic monitor. Also, `//` will resolve to the protocol in the browser.

Comment: It does not, I just tested it.

Comment: host.com/entry_point is different from host.com....(this is what the user types in )

Comment: and it doesn't matter wether or not I use a / or not in the internal .js file...this is how it works on my server atleast.

Comment: You should take this in chat and not in the comments.

Comment: What I guess is `/script.js` is same as `../scripts.js`. Am I right ?

Comment: @Jashwant: No. `..` just means "one directory up".

Comment: @Bergi, thx. That makes sense. I was always confused. And since I do not more than one level of sub directory, it always works for me :)

Comment: @Jashwant `..` indeeds refers to the parent folder, a useful property is that `/../scripts.js` equals `/scripts.js`. `.` refers to the current directory. (here, I talk about the structure of a path, not process properties)

Comment: I am consfused again `:(`. Suppose I am in xyz.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/test.html and I do `/../script.js` and `/scripts.js` , where would both take me ?

Comment: They'll take you to `xyz.com/script.js` and `xyz.com/scripts.js`. `/` is an absolute path. `..` is a hard link that points to the parent folder. So `a/b/../../z` equals to `a/../z` equals to `z`.

Answer (score 2):

You know where you're files are located. Use relative or absolute paths to them, and it will work both in PHP and JavaScript.

In your examples, the preceding `/` will make the paths point to somewhere else, breaking the application. In your PHP example, you especially concatenate the path string - it will depend on the evaluation of `getcwd()`.